# Microsoft Visual Studio 17.3.2 not allowing me to archive a successfully compiled project

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, archive

i just updated to VS 17.3.2 and when trying to archive a project that I previously successfully archived, and even successfully just compiled it, it is giving the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: ‘System.Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext/d__47::MoveNext()’ in assembly: ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll’ —> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.ReadOnlyMemory`1 Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HandshakeProtocol::SuccessHandshakeData
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedField(FieldReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
— End of inner exception stack trace —
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 AbuseAlert.Android
```

So, what is going on? I am even as at now able to run the project in the android emulator without any issues.